# Random letter in C [Segmentation fault]

Tags: c, arrays, char, segmentation-fault

I'm trying to generate some random names but I came across a problem. Here's how I try to choose a letter:

```
char alf[] = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
char letter = alf[rand()%26];  
printf("%s\n", alf);
printf("%s\n", letter);
```

It compiles but when I try to run it I get segmentation fault after first printf, and warning:

> format '%s'expects argument of type 'char*', but argument 2 has type 'int'

What do I do wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`letter` is a single char and as such, you should format it correctly by using `%c` instead of `%s`.

For more information on printf formats, visit this page: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/printf/?kw=printf